# drupal view rss having extra spaces

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, rss

I have created a feed view in drupal and i've set the Rss feed and all the settings properly but the problem is when i click on view feed it returns the page having space above the starting of the file as shown below.

```
     <?xmlns version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://cloud.ilinksys.com/feed.xml" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

The above space is already in the page. Anyone have any idea to remove the extra spaces of above the rss feed actual data.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually there's extra space before opening php tag `<?php` in `template.php` file or any other template or modules file which are called.